# Why does `return {};` not apply to `std::forward_list`?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, compiler-errors, clang

My compiler is clang 3.4, which completely supports C++14 and `std::forward_list`.

```
#include <forward_list>

struct A
{
    A()
    {}

    explicit A(initializer_list<int>)
    {}
};

A f1()
{
    return A(); // OK
}

A f2()
{
    return {}; // OK
}

typedef std::forward_list<int> T;

T f3()
{
    return T(); // OK
}

T f4()
{
    // error : converting to 'T {aka std::forward_list<int>}' from initializer 
    // list would use explicit constructor 'std::forward_list'     
    return {}; // ???
}
```

Why does `return {};` not apply to `std::forward_list`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, even if your compiler is C++14-compliant, your standard library isn't :)

C++11 has:

```
explicit forward_list( const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

whereas C++14 has (since [library DR2193](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2193)):

```
forward_list() : forward_list( Allocator() ) {}
explicit forward_list( const Allocator& alloc );
```

If you change `A`'s default constructor to `explicit A(char* = nullptr)` you'll see the same behavior.